# Form::select default value from GET variables

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have the following form:

```
            {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'get.index', 'method' => 'get')) }}
                {{ Form::label('order', 'Order by') }}
                {{ Form::select('order' , array('firstname' => 'First Name', 'lastname' => 'Last Name', 'state' => 'State')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Order results') }}
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

I'd like to make the selected option be the one which corresponds to the `order` variable (if any) in the query string. It should also default to the first choice if there isn't any query parameter.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php 
    $availableOrders = ['firstname' => 'First Name', 'lastname' => 'Last Name', 'state' => 'State'];
    $selectedOrder = Input::get('order', null);
    $selectedOption = !is_null($selectedOrder) && array_key_exists($selectedOrder, $availableOrders) ? $selectedOrder : 'firstname';
?>
{{ Form::select('order', $availableOrders, $selectedOption); }}
```

It's pretty selfdescriptive:

First you define an array of available order options.

Then you get the one that has to be selected from the query string.

If it's not null and an option with such array key exists - let's select it. If not - let's select the first one.

And once you have all these values you simply output it using blade and Form::select.

Don't forget that this can be done in fewer lines of code but this way the whole idea is very clear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation! However there are a few problems with it: if there is no order in the query string, it works as intended, but when there is, it adds a new, fourth option to the select, the one in the query string. This also wouldn't be a problem, but it adds the value instead of the text, which is a problem, since the app will be multilanguage.

Comment: Ok, could you please try to explain exactly what has to happen based on what. I'm pretty sure we're close to solving your problem here but to do that I have to fully understand what needs to be achieved.

Comment: Oh, wait. You don't need to add any new options. If there's an option with the same value the order param has it should be selected. If not - the first one should be selected. Am I right?

Comment: Yup, exactly this. Sorry if I didn't explain clearly in the first place!

Comment: just updated my answer. Didn't test it but should work just fine.